# .htaccess redirect www to non-www with SSL

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I have bought new domain and ssl for my website but I cant make redirect www to non-www.

It works when I enter www.new.com or www.old.com or old.com -> https://new.com

But when i trying to access: new.com it don't redirect me to https://new.com

How can I do this correctly?

```
<FilesMatch "\.(inc|php|php3|php4|php5|php6|phtml|phps)$">
AddHandler x-httpd-php56 .inc .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml
</FilesMatch>
##
# @package    Joomla
# @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2015 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that disallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## No directory listings
IndexIgnore *

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
#Options +FollowSymlinks
#Options -Indexes

## Mod_rewrite in use.
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^new\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://new.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new.com/$1 [L,NE,R=301]


## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Comment: Your second RewriteCond specifically demands that the host name _not_ be new.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a single rule for removing `www` and `http->https`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^new\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://new.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: I tried your way but I got error: The page isn't redirecting properly

Comment: Make sure this is very first rule and you clear your browser cache when you test it. If you have other rules as well then post your full .htaccess in question.

Comment: I updated question with additional htaccess code. I really appreciate your help in resolving the problem.

Comment: Did you completely clear your browser cache? What URL is causing redirect loop?

Comment: Yes, I cleared cache. All of the urls are causing loops.

Comment: Yes, it works. But when I trying to access `http://new.com` it won't me redirect to `https://new.com`

Comment: What is your hosting service and what is your Apache version?

Comment: My hosting provider is OVH and my apache version is 2.2.23.

Comment: ok but all this is working fine for me. I cannot really guess why is your hosting provider not supporting standard `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` condition.

Comment: I found a solution. I had to enable force ssl in Joomla! backend. Thank you for your help again.